# Android: Does android emulator support notifications when receiving sms like on real device?

Tags: android

I am developing an application that uses broadcast receiver to know whenever an sms is received and then show the notification in notification bar. In real app this works fine though but not in emulator, I send sms but there is no notification that sms has been received. Does emulator show notifications in the first place ? If not, is there someway we can check/see notifications in emulator ?

Thanks

Comment: You're sending SMS via DDMS, right?

Comment: @kamituel: via sms messanging app in the emulator. I am not sure what DDMS is :(

Comment: If you're sending SMS from within emulator, and trying to listen for SMS_RECEIVED broadcast? This broadcast is for incoming, not outgoing SMS's. Am I missing something?

Comment: @kamituel: yes i am sending SMS from within emulator, and trying to listen for SMS_RECEIVED broadcast. How would i then make emulator to check for SMS_RECEIVED broadcast, is there some way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test incoming SMS messages using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html).

From the doc:

> Spoofing calls or SMS text messages
>
> The Telephony Actions section of the Emulator controls tab lets you
>   spoof calls and messages. This is useful when you want to to test your
>   application's robustness in responding to incoming calls and messages
>   that are sent to the phone. The following actions are available to
>   you:
>
> Voice - Enter a number in the Incoming number field and click Call to
>   send a simulated call to the emulator or phone. Click the Hang up
>   button to terminate the call.
>
> SMS - Enter a number in the Incoming
>   number field and a message in the Message: field and click the Send
>   button to send the message.

If you're using Eclipse, you will find "Emulator Control" view, which you can use to send this fake SMS. In command line, use `ddms` executable which is in `$ANDROID_SDK/tools/`.